# Price and discount calculation in microservices

Tags: design-patterns, microservices, orchestration

I would like to ask about your ideas for pricing in microservices architecture.

Let's assume that the product has its standard price, which may be lower depending on whether the client is business or individual, whether there is a promotion for a given product and what conditions a given promotion has. For example, 30% discount promotion if there are> 3 products from the "A" category in the cart.

As you can see, the price can be lowered depending on many conditions.

Knowing this and that our data is in many databases - how to approach the calculation of the current price for a given customer?

Do you have an idea, design patterns?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Knowing this and that our data is in many databases

There is a pattern called [database per service](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html). So it looks like you are using this pattern. And further this documentation says:

> Keep each microservice’s persistent data private to that service and accessible only **via its API**. A service’s transactions only involve its database.

So if these conditions of lowering price are located in different databases:

- whether the client is business or individual
- whether there is a promotion for a given product and what conditions a given promotion has.

then it is possible to create API that provides a way to get data from these services. And then in your service you can set desired price based on this information

**UPDATE:**

According to [pattern DatabasePerSerivce](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html) you should have separate API for each service. E.g. `client` service should have own API, `promotion` service should have own API. And your
`price` service should get data from these services and make a desicion what price should be set.

Your services should contain business logic that belongs them. How can is it possible to divide logic acrsoss services? It is possible to apply single responsibility principle of SOLID principles. Read more about ["Pattern: Decompose by business capability"](https://microservices.io/patterns/decomposition/decompose-by-business-capability) in microservices.

Comment: Do you mean to aggregate some services (UserService, ProductService,...) in a gateway -if so, shoud I have a business logic there? Or do you mean to create an extra service eg. PricingService with getPrice method and in that service call all the required services (UserService, ProductService, ...).

Comment: @g_m please, see my updated answer

Comment: It seems you are suggesting to add an additional service (API) that will communicate with all required services in order to calculate the price. I assume that all services (and even the additional one) should be made available in the form of one API (ApiGateway). Or maybe I am assuming incorrectly and should I have a different API for the Client, different for Products, different for Pricing, etc. - one Gateway for one Microservice?

Comment: @g_m each service `client`, `pricing`, `products` should have own, separate API. Your another service `price` should poll these services such as `client`, `pricing`, `products` and based on this information it can decide what price should be set for product.

Comment: I assumed that I would have several APIs: SaleApi, ShipmentApi, SaleManagementApi and SaleApi would aggregate CustomersService, ProductsService, OrdersService. Whereas ShipmentApi will aggregate DeliveryService, OrdersService, CustomerService. Does this arrangement make sense? If so, where is the pricing (calculating) service in all of this? Is an additional service such as PriceCalculationsService aggregated by SaleService? By aggregating services, I mean providing selected services in the form of one API to the client, e.g. the client gets SaleApi and can operate on clients, orders, prices.

Comment: @g_m It is a really, really big architectural question and it deserves separate question with schemes. As a good practice it is better to have one question per topic. It imrpoves searchability, readability and responsibity. And you will get more attention by creating separate question with explanations.